# Shutter sound lags when capturing a photo and presenting new view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a camera app where a user takes a photo and then the photo is shown in a new view controller. It works fine except when a picture is taken, the iPhone shutter sound effect is really broken up during the view transition. I'm not sure why this is happening, but here is my code for taking a photo when the capture button is pressed... any suggestions?

```
dispatch_async(captureSessionQueue) {

        let connection = self.stillCameraOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        self.stillCameraOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(connection) { sampleBuffer, error 
             if error == nil {

                     let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)

                            if var image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                                let imageCapturedVC = ImageCapturedViewController(sourceImage: image, capturedImageOrientation: self.currentOrientation, session: self.session, imageBundle: self.imageBundle)

                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                    self.presentViewController(imageCapturedVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does the presented view controller have lots of CPU-intensive code, or blocking sync calls, in its setup methods (init*, viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, etc.)?

Comment: I don't think so. To be honest most of the code is taken from a template app where the camera shutter sounds fine.